# How to store Expression<Func<T, object>> in a class field?

Tags: c#, linq-expressions

I would like to store an Expression in class field to be used later.

Here is what i'm trying to do:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Expression<Func<Type, object>> _expression;

    public void SetExpression<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    {
        _expression = expression;
    }
}
```

Comment: `T` is not the same as `Type`. `Type` refers to an instance of [`System.Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=netframework-4.8), but `T` is a generic type parameter. Do you want your expression to take an instance of `T`, or to take an instance of a `Type` object as its input? They're very different things

Comment: Could you provide the error message?

Comment: `T` would need to be defined at class level. It currently only exists in the scope of your method.

Comment: i have used the Type in the field expresion, because there T would be an unknown type

Comment: The only unifying types between all `Expression<Func<T, object>>` are `LamdbaExpression`, `Expression` and `object`. You can use any of those to merely *store* the value, but that may not offer a convenient way to *use* the value. You don't show how you intend to use it, though, which makes it hard to say what the appropriate answer is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comment to the original question by @canton7 you are using `<T>` and `Type` but they are not the same thing.

A possible solution for this would be this:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    private Expression<Func<T, object>> _expression;

    public void SetExpression<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    {
        _expression = expression;
    }
}
```

Using this approach you would need to create the classes using the following

```
new MyClass<String>();
```

This would make the `_expression` be of type `Expression<Func<String, object>>`.

If you can't set `T` to a specific type on creation on the object you will need to pass the expression directly into the method you want to use it in, either that or make the type fixed for the stored Expression.

Comment: Your second proposed solution will not compile. You can't convert an `Expression<Func<T, object>>` to `Expression<Func<object, object>>`. You'd have to go all the way up to `Expression` (or `LambdaExpression`, I suppose, though that doesn't add much). It's also probably not desirable to simply do nothing if the type match should fail.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I didn't realise you couldn't, I guess the abstract version in the answer below is the solution. Or do you mean the SomeOperation()?

I agree it's not desirable, my aim was to give a possible solution, depending on the application you would log the issue or throw an exception. Could be any application so I was giving a general idea.

Comment: In my case I can´t use the generic type at the class level. And like @JeroenMostert said the second code does not compile

Comment: @MarcosLommez looking at your code more carefully it looks like what you want isn't actually possible without making the class generic or locking in what the type of the Func is. 

You best bet is to pass the expression into the method in which it is being used, and make that method generic

Comment: @TristanTrainer, i would like to not put the generic type at the class level..i will have to do a lot of changes... But this will have a better design
Thanks

Comment: No worries, I've had the same issue with Generics, wanting to use them but without being able to specify the type on creation, could do some really nice things if it were able to mark the type at run time with the type of the parameter passed in, however I guess you loss the power of a typed language doing that. So there are trade offs as always. Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

Hey is that what you want to achieve ?

```
public class MyClass<T>
    {
        private Expression<Func<T, object>> _expression;

        public void SetExpression(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
        {
            _expression = expression;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I beg to differ

Comment: add `using System.Linq.Expressions;` and it compiles (>= C# 3.0).

Answer (score 0):

Either create generic class:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    private Expression<Func<T, object>> _expression;

    public void SetExpression(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    {
        _expression = expression;
    }
}
```

Or use more "abstract" expression:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Expression<Func<object, object>> _expression;

    public void SetExpression(Expression<Func<object, object>> expression)
    {
        _expression = expression;
    }
}
```

In both cases if you working with type of input - you can get it by accessing input arguments of expression:

```
 var inputTypesWhichIWantedToBeGeneric = _expression.Parameters.Select(x=> x.Type);
```